# Using Firebase face detection to compare 2 faces

Tags: firebase, google-mlkit

Can I use [Firebase face detection](https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/vision/face-detection) to compare 2 faces (face pictures) and get the probability of them being the same ?

My usecase is to check if the person is the same across multiple pictures.

If not for using firebase ML, do you guys know what other ways exist to solve this problem ?

Thank you !

Comment: From your link: “Note that the API *detects faces*, it does not *recognize people*.”

Comment: Ya, thats correct. But can I use the multitude of parameters they give to calculate a probability score or something like that ?

Comment: Maybe? But I think it would be far too imprecise to be useful. Face ID, for example, uses 30 *thousand* data points.